# Alter selection text inserted into current selection element within select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange, jquery-select2

I'm using the jQuery plugin [select2](https://select2.github.io/) **V4** and my `select` field it's working off is a indented list as it's based off a parent/child relationship and the further down the tree the options go the more the indentation (`nbsp;`'s) is.

This displays fine in **select2**, however when you actually *select* an option, the *text* value that is inserted into the current selection element (`.select2-selection__rendered`) looks stupid as it contains a bunch of whitespace at the left.

Is there anyway to trim this whitespace before/after it is placed in the element?

I thought of trying to target the html content by getting the contents of the `select2-selection__rendered` element, but I wasn't sure how to target the correct element.

Something like..

```
$('select').on('change', function(e) {
    // Something here...
});
```

Won't changes done to the `e` target affect the actual `select` element, which I *don't* want.

Comment: Can you add a problem fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Working fiddle for older versions](http://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/fyhsz9ra/904/)**.

> Is there anyway to trim this whitespace before/after it is placed in the element?

Yes you could use a workaround by triming using `.trim()` the selected text and overwriting it using `text()` on change :

```
$('#my_select').on('change', function(e) {
    var selected_text_container = $('#s2id_my_select .select2-choice span');
    selected_text_container.text(selected_text_container.text().trim());
});
```

**[Working fiddle for version 4](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/wphqwvLf/666/)**.

In version 4 there's no `select2-choice` so use the generated id directly like :

```
$('#my_select').on('change', function(e) {
    var selected_text_container = $('#select2-my_select-container');
    selected_text_container.text(selected_text_container.text().trim());
});
```

Hope this helps.

**Version 4 :**

```js
$("select").select2();

$('#my_select').on('change', function(e) {
  var selected_text_container = $('#select2-my_select-container');
  selected_text_container.text(selected_text_container.text().trim());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://select2.github.io/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://select2.github.io/dist/js/select2.full.js"></script>
<select id='my_select' style="width:300px">
  <option value="AL">A</option>
  <option value="Am">&nbsp;&nbsp;A.a</option>
  <option value="An">B</option>
  <option value="Ak">&nbsp;&nbsp;B.a</option>
  <option value="WY">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;B.a.1</option>
</select>
```

**Older versions :**

```js
$("select").select2();

$('#my_select').on('change', function(e) {
  var selected_text_container = $('#s2id_my_select .select2-choice span');
  selected_text_container.text(selected_text_container.text().trim());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.2/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.2/select2.min.js"></script>
<select id='my_select' style="width:300px">
  <option value="AL">A</option>
  <option value="Am">&nbsp;&nbsp;A.a</option>
  <option value="An">B</option>
  <option value="Ak">&nbsp;&nbsp;B.a</option>
  <option value="WY">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;B.a.1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I don't understand where the `s2id_my_select` `id` comes from? I assume select2 uses the id of the select field and appends to it to make it's own `id`, but I don't see anything similar in my output? In fact I don't see any `select2-choice` classes either. Ahh, it could be because I am using select2 V4; I should of stated that.

Comment: That true, check my update i've added a new snippet using the select2 version 4 :)

Comment: Ahh, ok, I see it now in my output. Only thing though is you would need to know the ID of the select, so not real handy if you had multiple selects like this. I should be able to handle that myself by getting the id of the element and formatting it to look like `select2-my_select-container` :)

Comment: I see, here's the fix for multiple select https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/wphqwvLf/668/, you've just to give them a unique id's.